# How do you take the index of an object in an array and concatenate that value onto the object key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I have this array:

```
var arr =   [
  {
    itemCategory: "cats",
    itemSku: "12345",
    itemSubTotal: 10,
    itemQuantity: 2,
  },
  {
    itemCategory: "dogs",
    itemSku: "56789",
    itemSubTotal: 5,
    itemQuantity: 1,
  }
]
```

and I need this format:

```
var arr =   [
  {
    itemCategory1: "cats",
    itemSku1: "12345",
    itemSubTotal1: 10,
    itemQuantity1: 2,
  },
  {
    itemCategory2: "dogs",
    itemSku2: "56789",
    itemSubTotal2: 5,
    itemQuantity2: 1,
  }
]
```

How do I take the index number of the current object and append it to the key of the object?  The best I could do is this:

```
var newArr=[];
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    var obj = arr[i]; 
     for (var key in obj){
     var value = obj[key];
     var j = i;
     j = j+=1;
     newArr.push(key + j + ": " + value);     
     }
}
```

but it only gives me a flat array:

```
0: "itemCategory1: cats"
1: "itemSku1: 12345"
2: "itemSubTotal1: 10"
3: "itemQuantity1: 2"
4: "itemCategory2: dogs"
5: "itemSku2: 56789"
6: "itemSubTotal2: 5"
7: "itemQuantity2: 1"
```

Appreciate I'm only pushing it into an array, but I could not figure out how to update the object keys with those index numbers.

Thanks for any help; much appreciated.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), making the changes you are proposing makes the data structure far less flexible. What situation are you dealing with that requires the changes

Comment: Right, thanks for pointing that out @pilchard, I wasn't aware of the XY question.  I need to send it to Google Analytics (GA4).  GA will parse this format correctly in the http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Demo :**

```js
// Input array
let arr = [
  {
    itemCategory: "cats",
    itemSku: "12345",
    itemSubTotal: 10,
    itemQuantity: 2,
  },
  {
    itemCategory: "dogs",
    itemSku: "56789",
    itemSubTotal: 5,
    itemQuantity: 1,
  }
];

// Calculation to add index in each property of an object.
arr.forEach((obj, index) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((item) => {
    obj[item + (index + 1)] = obj[item];
    delete obj[item];
  })
});

// Result
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @ Creative Learner - this also works and is slightly less abstract for a beginner like me. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

In your code, this line:

```
newArr.push(key + j + ": " + value);
```

should be this:

```
newArr.push({[key + j]: value});
```

I thought it might be cleaner to map the keys over to a new object

```js
let arr = [{
    itemCategory: "cats",
    itemSku: "12345",
    itemSubTotal: 10,
    itemQuantity: 2,
  },
  {
    itemCategory: "dogs",
    itemSku: "56789",
    itemSubTotal: 5,
    itemQuantity: 1,
  }
]

arr = arr.map((a, i) => {
  let n = {}
  Object.keys(a).forEach(k => n[k + (i + 1)] = a[k]);
  return n;
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much @Kinglish, the map solution is spot on.  I'll spend some time looking at how it works over the weekend.  Have a good one

Comment: No prob. If this answered your question, consider marking it as the solution by clicking on the checkmark to the left. Cheers